# How to check that object with same ID (or any other attribute ) exists in array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, push, javascript-objects

I have following array:

```
var array = [
                {
                    "milestoneTemplate": {
                        "id": "1",
                        "name": "TEST1"
                    },
                    "id": "1",
                    "date": "1416680824",
                    "type": "ETA",
                    "note": "Note",
                    "color": "66FF33"
                },
                {
                    "milestoneTemplate": {
                        "id": "2",
                        "name": "Test 2"
                    },
                    "id": "2",
                    "date": "1416680824",
                    "type": "ATA",
                    "note": "Note 22",
                    "color": "66FF00"
                }
            ];
```

And now i would like to check in forEach loop that object (which is passed in param of the function) is existing in array by his ID.

In case that not = do push into existing array.

```
arrayOfResults.forEach(function(entry) {
                if(entry != existingInArrayByHisId) {
                array.push(entry);
}
        });
```

Thanks for any advice

Comment: have a look at [`array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a helper function thats checks if an array contains an item with a matching property value, something like this:

```
function checkForMatch(array, propertyToMatch, valueToMatch){
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(array[i][propertyToMatch] == valueToMatch)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

which you can then use like so:

```
arrayOfResults.forEach(function (entry) {
    if (!checkForMatch(array, "id", entry.id)) {
        array.push(entry);
    }
});
```