# How to check whether two Objects has few of the matching data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have data like this:

```
Array = [
  { 0: { Id: 18, Time: 3 } },
  { 1: { Id: 5, Time: 7 } },
  { 2: { Id: 18, Time: 10 } },
  { 3: { Id: 2, Time: 9 } },
];
```

As you can see `Object 0` & `Object 2` has same Id. 
I want to perform an operation which will check whether any of the Objects has same Id in it and return true or false.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27487694/10398005 this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The below code might help.

```js
function getMatch(array) {
  var idArray = array.map(a => a.Id);
  
  return idArray.some((a, index) => idArray.indexOf(a) !== index);
}

var arr = [
  { Id: 18, Time: 3 },
  { Id: 5, Time: 7 },
  { Id: 18, Time: 10 },
  { Id: 2, Time: 9 }
];

console.log(getMatch(arr));
```

Comment: Could you please suggest to do the same without using sort method ?

Comment: Actually, the variable name might be confusing as I was trying something with sorting to find a simpler solution. But here we are not sorting at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can map your array of objects its entries, and then map the entires to its `Id` to get an array of Ids. You can put this array of ids into a set to remove duplicates and compare it with the length of the array to check if an `Id` was removed when creating the set.

```js
const arr = [{ 0: { Id: 18, Time: 3 } }, { 1: { Id: 5, Time: 7 } }, { 2: { Id: 18, Time: 10 } }, { 3: { Id: 2, Time: 9 } }];

const ids = arr.map(Object.values).map(([{Id}]) => Id);
const hasSameId = ids.length !== new Set(ids).size;

console.log(hasSameId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function which will tell same id exist in your array.

```js
SameIdMatch() {
  let idList = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {
    if(idList.indexOf(Array[i].Id) === -1) {
        idList.push(Array[i].Id);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one liner.

```js
const input = [
  { 0: { Id: 18, Time: 3 } },
  { 1: { Id: 5, Time: 7 } },
  { 2: { Id: 18, Time: 10 } },
  { 3: { Id: 2, Time: 9 } }
];

const hasDuplicate = input.length !== [...new Set(input.map((item, index) => item[index].Id))].length;
console.log(hasDuplicate);
```